# Laravel 8 url segment always return null

Tags: php, laravel-8, validationrules

I created a validation for the creation and editing forms using Laravel's Request.

But I use the same form for creating and editing. So I created an exception so that when the url id is equal to the id registered in the database, it is allowed to insert the field that is configured as unique.

As you can see I'm using the segment to get the id that is being edited from the url, but it always returns null

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->segment(3);

    return [
        'name' => "required|min:3|max:255|unique:companies,name,{$id},id",
        'image' => 'nullable|min:3|max:255',
    ];
}
```

How can I get this id from the url? what am I doing wrong? In the Laravel 6 version I used the same method to get the id and I had no problems

Comment: What ```$this``` stands for ?

Comment: And please what is the url ?

Comment: $this refers to url

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, but I've solved the issue. The domain was considered as a segment of the url and we cannot consider it.

So the correct thing is

```
$id = $this->segment(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
$id = Request::segment(3);
```